# Angular mat-tab-group with ngFor : define tabindex dynamically

Tags: angular, indexing, tabs, ngfor

I have an angular web app in which a tab group must have a mandatory tab (to post a new object) and dynamical tabs (to edit existing objects).
I want to define precisely the tabindex values of the dynamical tabs in order to display one of them by default, so I tried this code :

```
<div class="div-center-card">
  <mat-tab-group #billingTabs>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let billing of billingList; let i = index" tabindex={{i+1}} label={{getLabel(billing)}}>
      <app-ast-billing-form [billingToEdit]="billing" formMode="put"></app-ast-billing-form>
    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab tabindex=0 label={{getLabel(null)}}>
      <app-ast-billing-form newLabelNumber={{getnewLabelNumber()}} formMode="post"></app-ast-billing-form>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the tabindex seems to be "-1" for all of the dynamical tabs.
What am I missing here?

[image: Chrome console screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to accessibility tabindex is not supported by Angular tabs. You can find the explanation on the tabs api: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api

Hope this helps!